# Dropdown Box from MySQL to remember selection after submit

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me with the following code? I have a dropdown box that is populated from a MySQL DB. All works fine but I would like it to remember the selection after the form has been submitted.

Code below:

```
$sql="select category_code, category_desc from members_categories";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$dropdown = "<select name='category_desc' size='1'><option value='%'>All</option>";

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$rows['category_code']}'>{$rows['category_desc']}</option>";

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;
```

Many thanks,

John

Comment: on form submit you can store its value in the session by using $_SESSION['some_index']=$_POST['category_desc'];

Comment: You have to save the select value in a session variable. With the next request you have to assign this var as value to the select control.

Comment: Do I need to reference the field using the selected command. Like in this code here - <option value="thing" selected>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you basically need to check in a loop if the submitted selection matches any selections being added to the html and if they do then insert the html `selected="selected"` to that element.

Here is an example of how it could work using your code:

```
$sql="select category_code, category_desc from members_categories";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$dropdown = "<select name='category_desc' size='1'><option value='%'>All</option>";

while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $checked = ($rows['category_code'] == $_POST['category_code'])? "selected='selected'":"";

    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$rows['category_code']}' $checked>{$rows['category_desc']}</option>";

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";


echo $dropdown;
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT That is assuming you will be showing the form again after**
If not then you need to just save the posted selection to the `$_SESSION` array and you will be able to access it from the `$_SESSION` array when ever you need it while the session is active at least.

have a read of this [basic php sessions examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)